# Linux server rejecting connections

Tags: linux, ssh

Whilst trying to run a Pentaho Job it failed stating "Error opening connection to [localhost] with username [pentaho]!" and with additional commentary "Authentication failed with username [pentaho]!".

All the job trying to do is running multiple connections in parallel and executing some Linux commands. For some weird reason (that I am not aware of) the job gets killed after exceeding some number of connections (some were successful and some were not).

`sshd_config` has default settings mostly and `PasswordAuthentication` is set to `yes`

`uname -a` returned 
`Linux pentahoserver 2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 14 02:46:51 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Content of `/var/log/secure`

```
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22593]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user pentaho (1000) tally 7, deny 6
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22593]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user pentaho (1000) tally 8, deny 6
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22582]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42522 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22521]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42517 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22516]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42515 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22582]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22521]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22516]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22788]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22786]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22516]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pentaho
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22521]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pentaho
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22866]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42545 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22841]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42544 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22866]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:24 pentahoserver sshd[22841]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23037]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42562 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23032]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42560 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23185]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[22866]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pentaho
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23339]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user pentaho (1000) tally 7, deny 6
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23117]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user pentaho (1000) tally 8, deny 6
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23336]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user pentaho (1000) tally 7, deny 6
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23186]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23339]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user pentaho (1000) tally 8, deny 6
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23338]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user pentaho (1000) tally 9, deny 6
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23117]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user pentaho (1000) tally 9, deny 6
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23336]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user pentaho (1000) tally 10, deny 6
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[22841]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pentaho
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23178]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42570 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23111]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42566 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23190]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42571 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23337]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42573 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23037]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23032]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23429]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42583 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23190]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23111]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23178]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23337]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23562]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23547]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23037]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pentaho
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23032]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pentaho
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23429]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23530]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42588 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23542]: Accepted password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42589 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23530]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23542]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pentaho by (uid=0)
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23612]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23624]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23178]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pentaho
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23190]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pentaho
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23785]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23542]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pentaho
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23786]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:25 pentahoserver sshd[23530]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pentaho
Jan 31 17:14:26 pentahoserver sshd[22593]: Failed password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42523 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:26 pentahoserver sshd[22599]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:27 pentahoserver sshd[23117]: Failed password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42567 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:27 pentahoserver sshd[23137]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:27 pentahoserver sshd[23338]: Failed password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42576 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:27 pentahoserver sshd[23348]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:27 pentahoserver sshd[23339]: Failed password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42577 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:27 pentahoserver sshd[23351]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
Jan 31 17:14:27 pentahoserver sshd[23336]: Failed password for pentaho from 127.0.0.1 port 42572 ssh2
Jan 31 17:14:27 pentahoserver sshd[23345]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: Closed due to user request.
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: It looks like the relevant log entries will be earlier than this. Please go back farther in the log.

Comment: Have you checked /var/log/tallylog yet? tally is clearly not happy with the account and disables it. Keep in mind that failed login attempts may not be caused by Pentaho itself. For instance, if this SSH server is reachable on the Internet you may suffer from script kiddies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not a direct answer to the problem you present, using the methods described below will prevent you from bumping into such issues in the first place.

I think it is considered a better practice to use private key authentication when running automatic jobs.

To do that, you need to generate a rsa ssh key in each machine you intend to ssh to and in the server where you run the commands (let's call it management server) from and then exchange the keys between the management server and the ssh client machines.

This will let you ssh from the management server to the ssh client servers without entering a password.

In addition to the ssh key exchange, I recommend you to check [this script](https://github.com/geek-kb/DevopsStuff/blob/master/Scripts/aws/paraexec.sh) that I wrote which wraps the "pssh" (parallel-ssh) command and enables you to supply the command a server.list file and a command and the script will run the command on each one of the servers in the list and will give you some colored indication as to the result of running the command on each server.

The use of this script requires you to install pssh which may also be known as parallel-ssh.

If you're not sure which steps you should take, let me know and I'll help you with the commands.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, we cannot change the authentication method. But what we can do is to identify the root cause of the existing problem and provide workaround/fixes. This means any changes to the property files are allowed